# How to get all connected nodes in neo4j graph in py2neo

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

Is there a way with py2neo to get all the connected nodes in a graph. All nodes that are connected by relationship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute a Cypher query that will return you those :

```
res = graph.cypher.execute("MATCH (n) WHERE size((n)--()) > 0 RETURN n");
for r in res:
    print r
```

Answer (score 0):

This Cypher query should be good enough:

```
MATCH (n)--() RETURN DISTINCT n
```

Comment: the query looks simpler, however if you compare the profiles, the solution I provided is really more performant