# Get the nodes which are all connected with my input node using py2neo and flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I want to fetch the connected nodes from ny neo4j database.
[image]

For example If I give the input as 2 and then I have to fetch 1,3,4 and 5.I tried to explore the question but answer is related to neo4j only. I need a query with py2neo. is there anyway i can get it?

I tried this
[How to get all nodes connected to one node in neo4j graph in py2neo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487787/how-to-get-all-nodes-connected-to-one-node-in-neo4j-graph-in-py2neo)
[How to get all connected nodes in neo4j graph in py2neo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483158/how-to-get-all-connected-nodes-in-neo4j-graph-in-py2neo)

But these are all with neo4j not with py2neo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your nodes have a property called `nodeid`, you can use [`NodeMatcher()`](https://py2neo.org/v4/matching.html#py2neo.matching.NodeMatcher) to match node `2` (see [Node Matching](https://py2neo.org/v4/matching.html#node-matching)), then iterate over its adjacent nodes:

```py
from py2neo import Graph, NodeMatcher

matcher = NodeMatcher(graph)

node = matcher.match(nodeid="2").first()

list(r.end_node["nodeid"] for r in graph.match(nodes=(node,)))
```

Otherwise, just run a cypher query:

```
q = '''MATCH (a)-[r]-(b) where a.nodeid='2' RETURN b'''
[i for i in graph.run(q)]
```